# Why won't circle CI recognise the ./gradlew assemble command?

Tags: android, android-studio, circleci

I am trying to get Circle CI to run an android studio build & generate a release `.apk` file.

It pulls in the SDK fine but after successfully bringing in the Android-SDK in my circle.yml file, as a dependency...

```
dependencies:
  override:
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-26.0.2,android-19,extra-google-m2repository,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-android-support
    - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies
```

my build fails with a:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies
bash: line 1: ./gradlew: No such file or directory

ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies returned exit code 127

Action failed: ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies
```

What am i doing wrong?
Why won't the ./gradlew command work?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it literally a few seconds after posting:

./gradlew is a file not a command. It's actioned when you're *in* the `android` folder.

To make sure I was definitely in android, i put a

```
general:
  build_dir: /android/
```

at the top